# How to send verification email in firebase from your email account?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

My question is pretty straightfoward. I want to know how to change the default sender email firebase provides you

> noreply@projectName.firebaseapp.com

To your Gmail or Outlook account. There's an option to "customize domain", but that requires you to *own* that domain. There is also an option of **SMTP services**, where you can *use your own SMTP server instead of the built-in email service*. I enabled it, completed the information required, hit save and it said "Settings updated". However nothing else happened, it didn't even checked if the user-password information was right. I would like to know if that's even possibble, or the SMTP has nothing to do with changing the email.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Firebase cloud functions

Send email like below

https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-email-using-node-js/

Comment: That's an option, but given that firebase the option already "integrated" I would like, if possible, to take advantage of that

Comment: This may help u https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-send-e-mails-using-firebase-extensions-a10d7cd685c2